# How do I find a sentence in which the beginning word is the same as the ending word?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am using egrep to find the lines qualified in a text, so how can I find a sentence in which the beginning word is the same as the ending word?

```
egrep '^(\w{2})\b.*$' filename
```

but this didn't seem to be correct

Comment: Please show an example of your input file. Especially: are all lines complete sentences or can a single sentence be split over several lines?

Comment: Try `sed -n '/^\([^[:blank:]]\+\).*\1$/p'`. Or using grep `grep -E '^([^[:blank:]]+).*\1$'`. This will only work on single line sentences.

Comment: For multi-line sentences ending in period, try `awk 'BEGIN {RS="."} $1==$NF'`.

Comment: @alvits sentences can also end in various other punctuation marks (e.g. `!`) and when you try to deal with that it gets complicated for non-GNU awks so it's not worth trying to guess what the OP might need if his/her input isn't just lines of space-separated text.

Comment: @EdMorton - I totally agree with you. Your assessment is probably what the OP has in mind by looking at the attempt made in the post.

Comment: And periods can appear in the middle of a sentence, said Mr. Ed.

Comment: @Lars Fischer. Like a poem. all lines are complete sentence and cannot be split over

Comment: @alvits what if the lines don't end in period, but just \n. I just changed to 'awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n"} $1==$NF' not sure if this works

Comment: @Amber - if the sentence is terminated by newline `\n`, then it isn't multi-line sentence any longer. In addition to `awk` you can use `sed` or `grep` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "word" and what your input and expected output looks like, this may or may not be what you want:

```
awk '$1==$NF' file
```

If it isn't then edit your question to provide all of the missing information.

Comment: Great answer. However the OP isn't clear with the input format. If sentences end in a period matters. If sentences span multiple lines matters. Add a caveat stating that your solution will work on single line sentences that doesn't end with a period. Or add multiple solutions for future readers.

Comment: Thanks. I already said it depends on everything the OP hasn't shared with us yet. There's too many possible input configurations to provide solutions for them all. If it doesn't work for the OPs real data then he'll hopefully update his question and someone will help him with that.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the the comment above, here are several options. I use an example input like this:

```
This has upper and lower case like this
That has also a full stop like that.
Here everthing is the same like Here
And here there is no match.
```

I use variations of this command: `egrep "^(\w+) .*\1$" testw.txt`

1. ignore case: add option `-i` : `egrep -i ...`
2. sentence end with punctuation: allow one optional char after the last word: `"^(\w+) .*\1.?$"`